# Como carregar a imagem no aspx

Tags: c#, aspx

estou tentando fazer um login onde o usuário possa carregar uma imagem, mas sem o uso do asp.net, eu sei que posso pegar o nome da imagem com o input, então só queria uma forma de  salvar a imagem e de mostrar para o usuário a imagem que ele escolhe